# How does TypeScript module resolution in Play work?

Tags: playframework, typescript, sbt, angular

I'd like to use Angular 2 with TypeScript in my Play project. I'm using the [`sbt-typescript` plugin](https://github.com/ArpNetworking/sbt-typescript) and the `angular2` WebJAR. When Play extracts the WebJAR, it puts it in `target/web/public/main/lib/angular2`. What I should be able to do in my `app/assets/js/components/test.ts` file is something like

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

but tsc is unable to resolve that, and I don't see any setting to tell it where to look.

Is this even currently possible? Would having a child project for just the TypeScript stuff make it easier?

Comment: it should be possible to configure stuff like this using a tsconfig.json file. maybe you could share yours?

Comment: I believe the tsconfig is automatically generated. Which option in there will be useful?

Comment: I'm inclinded to say **rootDir** or **filesDefinition** to configure a different root folder for the sources or definitions. You can find the full scheme for tsconfig.json here. http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

Comment: it would help if you could share the generated tsconfig.json.

Comment: also.. how do typescript files get in a war? if it's a deployable bundle only js files should end in it. :)

Comment: What looked like JSON for a jsconfig file actually seems to get passed as an argument to a script executed by Node.js that invokes the TS compiler. I'll see if adding one has any effect or if it gets overridden.

Comment: What WAR file are you referring to? I'm not generating one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* in fact currently possible to resolve Javascript/Typescript modules from your webjars dependencies. I've created a demo Play application that shows how.
See https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript

It uses a different [sbt-typescript plugin](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/sbt-typescript) that customises the module resolution. Thus working around the shortcoming that bpervan mentions.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm using your sbt plugin now, and things are going much more smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with same issue for a while, until I found that, currently, it is not possible.

See: https://github.com/ArpNetworking/sbt-typescript/issues/33

Current version of TypeScript transpiler does not support custom paths for module resolution, and, as it seems, it won't until version 2.0. You can check it out on official TypeScript Roadmap on their github repo (I'd love to paste link here, but SO doesn't allow me)

I guess, for now, that the only way to use angular2 with TypeScript in Play project is to let npm resolve dependencies for tsc. You may still use WebJars in Scala templates (SuperManitu left a link for his template in [1](https://github.com/ArpNetworking/sbt-typescript/issues/33), check it out (again, can't paste link, sorry))